# Lambda Function to Sum Tuple Values

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, lambda

I have a bunch of tuples that look like the following (this is `filtered` which I refer to later):

```
(10, 20)
(20, 40)
(30, 60)
```

I want to be able to sum the above tuples and produce one value (10 + 20 + 30) / (20 + 40 + 60) = `0.5`. I am trying to write lambda functions in pyspark to accomplish this, but I am not mapping them right. I currently have

```
totals = filtered.map(x, y: sum(x), sum(y))
```

but this doesn't seem to be working out so well. Is there something else I should be doing to accomplish this?

Comment: what is `filtered`?

Comment: @erik258 a bunch of tuples I created containing numbers from a csv I am using. filtered just removes some of the records I don't need.

Comment: Is it necessary to use RDD, or we can also use DataFrame to solve this problem?

Comment: I would like to use RDD @arudsekaberne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RDD (filtered)

```
(10, 20)
(20, 40)
(30, 60)
```

*Note: `map()` iterates through each row, therefore fetch each column values of a row in a variable and perform operation on top of it.*

```
col_a_sum = filtered.map(lambda row: row[0]).sum()
col_b_sum = filtered.map(lambda row: row[1]).sum()

total = col_a_sum/col_b_sum
print(total)
```

Output:

```
0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets use the spark's high level Dataframe API to aggregate the columns with sum  then collect the result and divide to calculate ratio

```
filtered = sc.parallelize([(10, 20), (30, 40), (50, 60)])

a, b = filtered.toDF(['a', 'b']).agg(F.sum('a'), F.sum('b')).collect()[0]
```

Result

```
a, b
# (60, 120)

a / b
# 0.5
```